# Check if click is on cell or free space inside QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyside, qtablewidget, pyside6

There is a fixed size QTableWidget with some rows and columns, the rest of the QTableWidget is blank and unoccupied. If the users doubleclicks on a cell, a dialog should be displayed, if the user doubleclicks on a blank area of the QTableWidget, a new row should be appended to the table.

I tried to solve it like this:

```py
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.cellDoubleClicked)

    def cellDoubleClicked(self):
        # display dialog here # 

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        event.ignore()
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        if not event.isAccepted():
            # add row to table
        return
```

but as I found out, the event gets never accepted. I think I did something stupidly wrong here. Now `mouseDoubleClickEvent`'s `if` gets called *every* doubleclick and `cellDoubleClicked` only if I doubleclick a cell. I tried to distinguish theses events by looking at `currentIndex` but that always points to the latest index selected, even after calling `clearSelection`. Is there an option to solve this based on my code stump or is it wrong all the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier than that: use [`indexAt(pos)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) which returns an *invalid* index if the position doesn't correspond to an existing item.

```
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if index.isValid():
            # show dialog
        else:
            # add row to table
```